# How to avoid generating pdf-file per figure in sweave?

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, figure, sweave

Sorry if I'm asking a stupid question, but I'm kinda new to R/Sweave.
I have noticed that if I run my file, RStudio automatically generates a pdf-file for each figure plotted (as well as a pdf-file containing all generated figures from the Sweave-file). For example, suppose I have the following chunk of code in RStudio (simplified version):

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
<<fig1, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
   plot(pts.X,1:length(pts.X),
        main = "Type I error for X-var IT")
@
\caption{}
\label{X-var}
\end{figure}
```

Then, RStudio saves a pdf-file called *R/SweaveFileName-fig1.pdf* as well as a pdf-file *Rplots.pdf* which will also contain any other figure included in the Sweave-file. Since my R/Sweave files contain a lot of figures, I was wondering whether it is possible to change this option in R/Sweave. And, if not, is it possible to redirect these pdf-files into a separate folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid generating the figures.  RStudio isn't really doing much of the work here; it's just directing other software to do it.

- R generates the figure, and the LaTeX source code to import it.
- LaTeX imports the figure and produces the final .pdf for the whole document.

You can tell R to put the files in a particular place using `\SweaveOptions{prefix.string = figs/}`.  Put this into your document somewhere
pretty early, and all figures will be put into a directory called "figs" (which must exist for this to work).

For more details about the options in Sweave, see the vignette in the `utils` package.